# Does YAFFS filesystem support ECC more than 1 bit per 256 byte page?

Tags: c, algorithm, flash-memory

From YAFFS2 source (yaffs_ecc.c):
"The ECC can correct single bit errors in a 256-byte page of data."

But some flash memory requires ECC code, that, for example, must correct 8 bit per 540 byte, or 4 bit per 528 bytes, etc.

Can ECC algorithm from YAFFS correct more than 1 error? Please give me link on ECC algorithm realization, that can correct more than 1 error and work fastest.

Comment: Could you add a link to the source code you reference?

Comment: can you mention which flash memory you are using

Comment: http://www.yaffs.net/downloads

Comment: Macronix MX60LF8G18AC https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAAahUKEwiS9eaKsJ7IAhXnqXIKHbogBdI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.macronix.com%2FLists%2FApplicationNote%2FAttachments%2F929%2FAN-0365V1-MGRT_MX60LF8G28AB%2520to%2520MX60LF8G18AC(MAR04).pdf&usg=AFQjCNGnRFJ2HzmmxIFTDtbyRSlQ9UHzUQ&bvm=bv.103627116,d.bGQ&cad=rjt  On first page you can see ECC requirement for 2 models of Macronix flash.

Answer (score 1):

YAFFS is Nand based file system. The file system is designed based on the architecture of the nand flashes.

Can ECC algorithm from YAFFS correct more than 1 error?

No it cant correct more than 1 bit error.

As per the nand architecture for every page one ECC is maintained and it can handle up-to 1-bit error. If ECC shows more than 2 bit error then its  un-correctable error and the page is marked bad block.

Even if you try to implement an ECC algorithm in yaffs the flash memory will not be able to be handle the error correction. Spare area will be maintained in the flash to store the ECC bits and there is limited number of bytes to store this data.

In order to modify the file system you can check the data sheet of the flash you are trying to implement. And most of the flash has internal ECC generation controller i.e hardware controller.

can correct 8 bit per 540 byte?

It will be too complex to implement such an algorithm for flash.

Here are the some of the ECC algorithms used for flash memories

1. Hamming Algorithm
2. Reed-Solomon Algorithm
3. Bose-Chaudhuri-Hocquenghem (BCH) algorithm

> There is possibity of correcting more errors using BCH algorithm this
>   algorithm is implemented mostly in hardware controller